# How to fire SQL query on Open worksheet of Excel sheet on runtime?

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing code to generate an Excel file.
I am generating a detailed report in 3 sheets in single XLS file.
I am able to write 1 detailed, sheet1.
Now I want to fire SQL query on sheet1 table to generate sheet2 table.

My sheet1 contains 9 columns. Out of 7, one is price.
I want to fire query like this:

```
Select Product_Name, City, State, Country,  SUM(price), Sub_Type, Description from Sheet1 Group By Product_Name, City, State, Country, Sub_Type, Description
```

...and save both work sheets.

How can I Fire such query, or use some other method to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a pivottable on sheet2, that get's its input from sheet1.